# Why can't I make clickable links for my HTML code?

Tags: html

I want to make an image for my code a link so that people can click it, but whenever I upload the code to my file, I can never click it. Can someone please help? Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<style>
img.transp {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); 
}
</style>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<title>
Home - Stampycraft.net 
</title>
</head>
<body>
<center> 
<h1> 
<a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="gaoosh.gif" /></a>

</h1> 
</center>
<div style='position:absolute;z-index:0;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%'>
  <img class="transp" src=stampy6.png style='width:100%;height:100%' alt='[]' />
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is covering it:

```
<div style='position:absolute;z-index:0;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%'>
  <img class="transp" src=stampy6.png style='width:100%;height:100%' alt='[]' />
</div>
```

Remove that code and you'll see what I mean.

An alternative:

```
<div style='position:absolute;left:0;top:0;'>
  <img class="transp" src=stampy6.png alt='[]' />
</div>
```

Comment: Is there away to keep this code and also make a link? Or is there an entirely different code? Thanks for answering.

Comment: No, but you could approach the problem differently. is stampy6.png your logo? You could set it as the page background, float it top left, etc. Without actually seeing the images, it's hard to tell what you want it to do/look like.

Comment: stampy6.png is already the background image, which I have made transparent. What I want to do is make the image that I have (gaoosh.gif) clickable.

Comment: Well, it's not a background image. That's the problem. You have it set to fill the page, and it gets in front of your content. I'll post an alternative in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

change the 100% with less value like 10%, the image is hidden the link, thats why you cannot click it.

Comment: `the image is hidden the link, thats why you can click it.` Shouldn't this be `the image is hiding the link, that's why you cannot click it`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I found out a solution! The "z-index" part of my code is at 0 (which shows that it has higher priority over my image (gaoosh.gif). So, I inserted this handy piece of code and:

```
h1{ 
 position: relative; 
top: 30px;
left: 50px;
z-index: 1;

}
```

Voila! My image is now clickable.
But anyways, I want to thank you all of you who helped answer my question.